# How to best get Qt Designer for QGIS plugin development on Mac?

Tags: pyqgis, mac, qt, qt-designer

I'm using QGIS 2.6.1 on Mac OSX 10.9.4, trying to create a plugin as described in the PyQGIS Programmer's Guide. I have the plugin 'skeleton' (main widget with header and ok/cancel buttons) running in QGIS, and I want to edit the plugin with Qt Designer.

I haven't installed Qt on its own and I don't really understand if, by having compiled and installed PyQt and QGIS, I already have Qt Designer installed. I know the Qt Designer classes are available in PyQGIS, and when I run:

/usr/sbin/system_profiler SPFrameworksDataType

I find:

```
QTKit:

  Version: 7.7.3
  Obtained from: Apple
  Last Modified: 1/26/15, 1:23 PM
  Kind: Intel
  64-Bit (Intel): Yes
  Signed by: Software Signing, Apple Code Signing Certification Authority, Apple Root CA
  Get Info String: QTKit 7.7.3, Copyright 2003-2012, Apple Inc.
  Location: /System/Library/Frameworks/QTKit.framework
  Private: No
```

I really don't want to confuse things by installing a separate version of Qt if I don't have to- but I can't for the life of me figure out how to open Qt Designer or any of the Qt modules without first separately downloading and installing Qt.

Should I download and install Qt or can I already use Qt Designer? If I already have Qt Designer, how can I access it (preferably from command line)?